# How do I avoid getting the HTTP status code 405?

Tags: javascript, http, http-status-code-405

Im trying to use the tvdb.com API ([docs](https://api.thetvdb.com/swagger#!/Authentication/post_login)). For now, I'm just trying to connect and get a JWT token using the /login operation. However I'm running into the HTTP status code [405](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag3jk.png).

Here the code I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
    <p id="demo">Demo</p>
    <input type="button" value="Button" id="button" onclick="callAPI();">
</body>

<script src="app.js"></script>
```

app.js :

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = "https://api.thetvdb.com/login";
const data = JSON.stringify({"apikey":"/*APIKEY*/"});

xhr.responseType = "json";
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
        console.log(xhr.response)
    }
}

function callAPI(){
    xhr.open("POST",url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

[OPTIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkTne.png)

Doesnt it say here that I may use POST?

Comment: The server is rejecting the preflight. To stop the preflight from being sent, omit the additional request headers.

Comment: 405: "Method not allowed".  One reason for this might be that you're using POST (or PUT, or HEAD or OPTIONS) when you're not supposed to.  (PUT and/or OPTIONS are used in preflight, which @KevinB is referring to)

Comment: er, no. it's failing in this case because OPTIONS isn't the expected verb. the server isn't configured to handle preflights properly, at least on that particular route if not all of them.

Comment: It might actually be complaining about POST when it's expecting GET - but that would be unusual, POST is generally preferable for a login

Comment: And remove `json.stringify` only `var data = {"apikey":"APIKEY"};` should work

Comment: Doubful that his key is literally "APIKEY" unless that's a dev mode placeholder

Comment: The api said that it should be post, but there are missing parameters too like username and userkey, `{
  "apikey": "string",
  "userkey": "string",
  "username": "string"
}`

Comment: It seems like the server isn't configured to handle cross-origin requests. If I'm reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) correctly, it should be sufficient to remove the `Content-Type` header to keep the preflight OPTIONS request from being sent. I would guess that the server doesn't even look at the request's declared content type and always assumes JSON.

Comment: @YouneL This doesnt change anything. They are completely optional, as stated here [link](https://api.thetvdb.com/swagger#!/Authentication/)

Comment: @Blurp Now I'm getting the status code 415.

Comment: Did you try leaving out all the request headers as suggested by @KevinB? Perhaps the API isn't meant to be used directly via AJAX?

Comment: @Blurp I did this and am getting status code 415 now. So is the issue related to the `const data = JSON.stringify({"apikey":"/*APIKEY*/});` section?

Comment: I guess their API is meant to be called from server-side code where this wouldn't be an issue (which would also avoid exposing your keys to the public internet). Their docs aren't very helpful, though, so it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: @Blurp Thanks for the help! I'll try to implement this in node.js to resolve it

Comment: You can probably use ajax GET once you have the token doing a server side post for login

Comment: @charlie yeah, but you need to refresh the token every 24h. So it makes more sense to me to just make it all server side.

Comment: I agree. What I have done before is store expire time and if request is close to that do a request for refresh token and use that to get data and add another 24 h to it (assuming that's how this api works)